# How can I use Selenium RC to verify our Server-Side-Redirects (301, 302)?

Tags: apache, redirect, selenium, selenium-rc

We have a bunch of redirects in our Apache configuration. I would like to automate the testing of redirects with Selenium, which led me to some problems:

- Call an URL, but assert on the redirected page
- Check the URL of the browser after redirected
- Check Response Header, to determine the type of redirection (301, 302)

Maybe Selenium is not the best solution for this. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Just out of curiousity why do you need to do this in a browser? Why not do it at a lower level?

Comment: You are right. In fact, I think I wanted to use the wrong tool for this. Yesterday I created unit tests with simple HttpClient and a modified RedirectStrategy to analyze the Response for redirect status and location header. It works very good, without even starting a browser session.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Selenium-RC has a traffic capture mode, defined as `selenium.start("captureNetworkTraffic=true");` that will enable you to capture HTTP responses, including redirects and error codes.

[Here](http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2009/10/automated-webhttp-profiler-with.html) is an excellent resource on how to capture and process/format this information once retrieved. It uses Python, though, but should give you a start.

For checking the URL of browser, you could use `selenium.getLocation();`

Answer (score 1):

in python's implementation,

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
print driver.current_url
```

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver