# How to get page source before redirect?

Tags: selenium

How to get page source (or element) before redirect?

```
self.browser.get(url)
element = self.browser.find_element_by_name(name)
```

Comment: How fast is the redirect? Because you can do it by method `getPageSource` easily...

Comment: Very fast, I try use getPageSource and getPageSource return me redirected page.

Comment: Have you seen the question [How can I use Selenium to verify our Server-Side-Redirects (301, 302)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168473/how-can-i-use-selenium-to-verify-our-server-side-redirects-301-302)

You can use captureNetworkTraffic=true.

Comment: How can I set set this property for FireFox WebDriver?

Comment: @Gr1N That seems to be a new question! :-)